# How can i get print button counter on watermark of the duplicate invoices in qweb in odoo 10

Tags: xml, odoo, qweb

I have got the watermark of Copy of Original in invoices of odoo but the problem is i need it with print button counter like 'Copy of original 1', 'Copy of original 2'. It should increase as the button is being clicked. How can i do it??

```
    <span>
    <div
                        style="position:absolute;opacity:0.45;z-index:-1;transform:rotate(300deg);-webkit-transform:rotate(300deg);top:400px;text-align:bottom;width:100%;">
                        <p style="font-size:100px;">Copy of Original</p>
                        <t t-set="nbr_page" t-value="0" />
                        <p>
                            <t t-set="compteur" t-value="nbr_page+1" />
                        </p>
                    </div>
    </span>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify seperate page number for your invoice print right?
Here you go:

```
<span>Page </span><span class="page" /> of <span class="topage" />
```

> Result:

Eg:
If there is 12 pages,your first page will be: `Page 1 of 12`

NB: Edit it to your needs.Thanks

Comment: Thank you for the answer but what i am trying to get is if i clicked the duplicate button for the first time to get the duplicate invoice, it should reflect "Copy of original 1" and if i clicked again for the duplicate invoice for thte next time it should reflet "Copy of original 2". The page counter must increase as the duplicate button being clicked.

Comment: Ok.You are having a custom button for printing duplicate invoice right?

Comment: No. Can i do that by the default duplicate button??

Comment: Default duplicate button for print..!!! I haven't seen that.. Is that your custom button..?